# Mounting s3 to a docker container without privileged or SYS_ADMIN mode

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, kubernetes, airflow

I am using apache airflow with Kubernetes. I am able to mount s3 in scheduler and webserver using s3fuse but worker pods don't take container level `securityContext` which makes it impossible to add privileged mode to the container.

Is there any way to mount s3 to a kubernetes pod/Docker container without the priviledged or SYS_ADMIN mode

Comment: [**@AyushChauhan**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6541898/ayush-chauhan) maybe able to explain the associated pitfalls of using s3fs with airflow. I recall 2 of them (1) slow speed (2) garbage characters being read from DAG code

Comment: Doesn't matter for the experiment I am trying currently

Answer (score 0):

how about "https://github.com/kuberenetes-learning-group/fuse-device-plugin/blob/master/README_EN.md"

it works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).